# SAP GUI script with LiveConnect: java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: javascript, java, sap-gui

I've got a Script on JS using LiveConnect (*) which I run on SAP GUI Java 7.80 (**), it should return the path of the file by filepicker, but it returns an error messagebox after executing:

> Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "com.sap.platin.base.util.GuiKeyboardFocusManager.focusLock" "read")

This is the script (*):

```
var utils = application.utils;
utils.showMessageBox("Info", "Starts OK", utils.MESSAGE_TYPE_INFORMATION, utils.MESSAGE_OPTION_OK);

filePath=openFileChooser();

 
function openFileChooser ()
{
var filePath;

try
{
chooser = new Packages.javax.swing.JFileChooser(); 
retVal = chooser.showOpenDialog (null);

if (retVal == Packages.javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
}catch (e)
    {
    application.utils.showMessageBox ("Error in openFileChooser",
    "Exception: " + e, 0, 0);
    }

return filePath;
}
```

Though I've found one syntax error in the user guide code, maybe the code is also not correct. Maybe that's something with SAP permissions in Linux?

I found SAP for Java permission instruction [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/f540a730ff3c46a29c34be1fd3cd3275/780.00/en-US/sap_gui_for_java.pdf) (***), but I don't understand what I should write to let the filepicker work.

---

**(*)** I've copy/pasted the script from the document [SAP GUI Scripting User Guide](https://synactive.com/download/sap%20gui%20scripting/sap%20gui%20scripting%20userguide.pdf) - Release 620 > chapter "JavaScript Engine for SAP GUI for Java" > "LiveConnect".

**(**)** SAP GUI for Java 7.80 
   (Version ID 078000040000) 
   2022-08-24 02:02:37 +0000 
   xxxx, 780_REL, 2152127 
   Java VM: SAP SE Version 17.0.4+8-LTS 
   OS: Linux(amd64) Version 5.15.72-1.el7.3.x86_64

**(***)** Source: [SAP GUI for the Java Environment](https://help.sap.com/doc/f540a730ff3c46a29c34be1fd3cd3275/780.00/en-US/sap_gui_for_java.pdf) - Document Version: 7.80 – 2023-03-07 > chapter "5.3 Security Policy"

Comment: To see if it's an issue Java or SAP GUI-related, do you have the same permission error if you select the file manually via SAP GUI? (use any SAP Transaction Code you want where you can select a file)

Comment: @Sandra Rossi Tried, SAP has permission to pick the files from local disk.